# write to file in swift 3 transforming the data from json to xml

Tags: json, xml, swift3, writetofile

notice below that cats is of type json returning from the server, and when I use `try! cats?.write(toFile: file, atomically: false)`
the file contains an xml output while i need to stay as json, any help is much appreciated!

```
let text = ""
try! text.write(toFile: file, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

let parameters : NSMutableDictionary? = [`enter code here`]

let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

manager.post("http://appsandgamesinc.com/api/AppAsUser/getMedias/", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { (task: URLSessionTask, responseObject) in
      let response = responseObject as? NSDictionary
      let medias = response?.object(forKey: "medias") as? NSDictionary

      let cats = medias as? NSDictionary
      print("cats:\(cats)")
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: medias)

      try! cats?.write(toFile: file, atomically: false)

      print("file://"+file)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of cats is `NSDictionary` if you want to save JSON in file then save it using data. Also with Swift use Swift's native Dictionary and `Array` instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`.

```
manager.post("http://appsandgamesinc.com/api/AppAsUser/getMedias/", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { (task: URLSessionTask, responseObject) in
    if let response = responseObject as? [String:Any],
        let medias = response["medias"] as? [String:Any] {

        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: medias) {
            try? data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: file), options: .atomic)
        }
        print("cats:\(cats)")
        NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: medias)                      
        print("file://"+file)
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it works but i still have one problem:
what is supposed to look like this:
http://dg7csqkdaad2n.cloudfront.net/Media/2262089580297_1494328417.jpeg

is coming out like this:
http:\/\/dg7csqkdaad2n.cloudfront.net\/Media\/2262089580297_1494328417.jpeg

and i'm not parsing the content of the file so i can't fix it programmatically any ideas?

thanks again

Comment: @user3411226 Don't get your problem

Comment: the urls in the file look like this:
http:\/\/dg7csqkdaad2n.cloudfront.net\/Media\/2262089580297_‌​1494328417.jpeg

which gives errors and is not accessible

Comment: @user3411226 That file contains url like that or its because of programatically storing JSON ?

Comment: this is stored programmatically after writing to the file

Comment: @user3411226 Can you show me the JSON response that you receive from your request